# What kind of knowledge is required to program a simple safe working boot sector?

Tags: assembly, x86, boot, sector

I know knowledge of assembly is the very first thing needed (which I have), and I also know that Boot Sector code tells the processor to boot/execute a program (or OS), but what I don't is the HOW of it. I've seen disassembled bootsector code, but I don't know how to write that code. If I write a malfunctioning bootsector code to my USB flash drive, it will never work again.

I can always get tidbits of programming boot sectors from the internet but I'm looking for an organized tutorial or something like that, where they teach how to program a boot sector and other boot programs from beginning to end. Please point me in the right direction...

Comment: This might help http://kos.enix.org/pub/bootwrit.html http://susam.in/articles/boot-sector-code/

Comment: http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page

Comment: the system isn't actually going to try to boot a thumb drive when you attach it, not if it's already booted. I.e., you should be able to recover from failed experiments. If you try to boot a system from a bum USB stick, unless the boot code was really, really bad, it should be fine if you pull the stick out and reboot the system. It's hard to see how you could permanently screw up your system with just 512 bytes of assembly, though of course, virus writers manage to do so.

Comment: Another thing: Use a virtual machine and/or emulator to test your code and when you test on actual hardware only do so on stuff you're OK with breaking.

Comment: @JustJeff don't the first 512 bytes of code get executed, when the pen drive is only inserted into the computer? As i know, those instructions **are** read by the computer before any drivers can be loaded..right?

Comment: @user786653- that link was really helpful, although they concentrate on OS development.. :-)

Comment: @Rushil - if you're thinking of the way things automatically happen when you plug a thumb drive into an already-booted computer, what you're seeing is *autoplay*; the OS looks at the partition tables and directory structures in a formatted stick, so it can map the stick's file system into the machine's own file system, and then, if there's an autoplay.inf file, and autoplay isn't disabled, the system will run something from the stick - but it isn't *booting* the stick.

Comment: Ya that surely isn't booting the stick, but I had heard somewhere that the MBR of a thumb drive gets read/executed whenever it gets plugged into a computer (for getting info about the partition tables)..

Answer (score 0):

There is two MBR actually. First is master boot record (MBR) and second is volume boot record (VBR). Both participate in the bootstrapping of operating system. MBR structure differs from VBR in this way - MBR basically starts with your assembly code and ends with patrition table information, VBR starts with jump to your assembly code which is placed after some volume information. When system starts it reads MBR into memory at physical address 0x7c00 and jumps to that address. It is supposed MBR's responsibility to read partition table (loaded together with MBR as it's part) and to find actual volume (disk drive such as C,D,E,... in terms of Windows), where an operatig system is expected to be. After MBR has found OS volume it loads it's VBR again at the address 0x7c00 and then jumps to the mentioned address. Now VBR reads it's volume information (loaded with it as it's part) and decides where to find operating system bootstrap code. After decision is made - VBR loads OS bootstrap code and jumps to it's starting address.

Having this information you can see the required boot record writer knowledge. At least - you should know wich boot record you are writing (MBR or VBR). Then you can read about it's data structures and write code capable of reading them and loading next chunk of bootstrap code.